# Making Ionic 2 project work after cloning from git

Tags: git, angular, ionic2

I have a working app (Ionic 2 Beta 7). I pushed to my Github, then git cloned into a different folder.

In the new folder, I ran `npm install` and `ionic state restore` for dependencies, and added android platform.

However, `ionic serve` **still produces a blank app.**

The only error message in Chrome's dev tools is

> http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have read different topics  but haven't managed to make it work.
I tried `bower install` & running cmd as admin, nothing.

For the record, everything is on C:\ drive, where Node is installed as well.

Comment: The first thing you probably want to do is make sure Ionic-CLI and Cordova are up to date:
 
`npm install -g cordova ionic@beta`

Comment: As I said below, the project was built with Ionic2 beta7 and that's the one I have on my machine. I do not want to update to the latest version as that will break it (there was significant changes in Ionic 2 beta8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an error in the config.
Steps to solve:

1. Find the file `package.json` in project root
2. Edit the line
   `"ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.1.0"` to
   `"ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "1.1.0"` **[remove the caret (^)]**.
3. Run `npm install`

My issue was that I had only run npm install in the beginning, but you need to run it **after** you fix the dependency issue in `package.json`.

Link to Ionic forum fix post:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-not-generating-app-bundle-js/55640/3

Answer (score 1):

As @lthh89vt noted, this happens on TS errors. To have it build anyway, pass `{ onError: e => console.error(e.toString()) }` to `ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript`'s options.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when ionic cannot compile your typescript to build directory.

So as @sebaferreras mentioned, you probably want to check your cordova & ionic version and make sure you are running ionic 2

```
cordova --version
ionic --version
```

You can run npm `install -g cordova ionic@beta` to install ionic 2

If the issue persists, perhaps you want to the build log.

You should see something like this: [Ionic build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgrGy.png)

Just make sure there is no error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The project was developed on Ionic 2, beta7 - and that's what I have installed. I do not want to update as that will break it further (changes after beta8).
I am seeing the build log and it seems fine. But still blank page.

Comment: Good that you found the answer ^_^.
My case was installing ionic v1 and it override the v2 beta.